# ASP.NET Core DI: Resolve same instance if scoped service is registered both as service type and implementation type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

Say I have a service that I want to resolve with a scoped lifetime. But sometime I try to resolve it as the interface type and sometimes at the implementation type.

The first thing I tried to do was this:

```
ServiceCollection services;
services.AddScoped<MyClass>();
services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
```

The problem with the above sample is that a different instance is used if I resolve IMyInterface, and than resolve MyClass. Basically it's possible that 2 scoped instances are alife at the same time.

I work around this issue in the following way. But it's very error-prone because you can easily forget to do this at one place, and it's really hard to notice.

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<MyClass>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyClass>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MyClass>());
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I want in a way that is less error prone. Preferrably, but not necessarily, in a single registration?

I.e. as an xUnit test:

```
public class Tests
{
    [Fact]
    public void ReturnsSameInstanceForImplementationAndServiceType()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // TODO: Change these lines so they're less error prone.
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<MyClass>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyClass>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MyClass>());

        var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        var myInt = services.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>();
        var myCls = services.GetRequiredService<MyClass>();

        Assert.Equal(myCls, myInt);
    }

    class MyClass : IMyInterface { }
    interface IMyInterface { }
}
```

Comment: Why are you registering the implementation at all?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto While I agree it's not best practice. I work with an old and kind of big code-base where the implementation is injected at a lot of places. Not really able to change this to the interface at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to create your own extension method that wraps up the two lines you've shown in your question. For example:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddScopedInterfaceAndClass<TInterface, TClass>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        where TInterface : class
        where TClass : class, TInterface
    {
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<TClass>();
        serviceCollection.AddScoped<TInterface, TClass>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<TClass>());
    }
}
```

You could call this like so:

```
serviceCollection.AddScopedInterfaceAndClass<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
```

I appreciate that `AddScopedInterfaceAndClass` isn't the perfect name - it's just an example to demonstrate the idea. Also, there is still the downside that you'd have to *remember* to use this extension rather then `AddScoped`.

Note: You could simplify the second `AddScoped` in the extension method by removing the second generic (`TClass`) as this is inferred by the compiler.